# How to calculate new lat and long from current location + 500 meters

Tags: java

I have lat and long of current location is 51.0447° N, 114.0719° W and i have N number of entries in Database table with Lat and long i have to pull list of entries that have lat long within 500m from current locations

Comment: To convert lat and lon to a position that you can offset with metres you need to take the geographical position and translate it into a metres for this you need to apply a spheroid and projection.  The spheroid and projection you apply depends entirely on where on the planet you are as contrary to popular belief the world is not a perfect circle but a spheroid, the spheroid and projection description the shape of the planet in the area you are and give mathematical parameters to translate the degrees, minutes and decimal minutes into metres.

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/5821/calculating-latitude-longitude-x-miles-from-point - here is the calculation explained on stackexchange. Not sure if it is correct but you might give it a go, implementing it in java shoulnd't be too hard.

Comment: @Amongalen, just taken a look at that, its not correct, you cannot apply the same figures to every location on the planet... I use to work in survey and navigation writing software to do just this.  On a piece of paper if you draw a straight line between two points on a map, when this route is applied to the plant it is translated into a curve, this is called "great circle" and because its a curve there is no constant to apply, the spheroid and projection changes as you move on the planet.

Comment: Please consider asking - or looking for an existing answer - in [GIS Stack Exchange](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). This link is to the help page, please read their help pages to see if your question is on-topic, and search, as it is very likely to already be answered there.

Comment: I once implemented a [`BoundingBox`](https://github.com/COVID19-PIRAT/backend/blob/code_improvment_distance_function_issue_29/Pirat/Services/Helper/BoundingBox.cs) in C# that well tries to find more like a bounding region (with the helper class [`Location`](https://github.com/COVID19-PIRAT/backend/blob/code_improvment_distance_function_issue_29/Pirat/Services/Helper/Location.cs)) But I dont guaratee correctness of the code. This kind of calculation has many egde cases. Like the poles and the points where -180° turns to 180°.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you could use the [Proj](https://proj.org/) library to help you do this, it should be able to do most of the heavy lifting for you.